# Check for the existence of an dict and then only define it

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

python3

```
>>> a = dict()
>>> a['id1'] = dict()
>>> a['id1']['a'] = 5
>>> a['id1'] = dict()
>>> a['id1']['b'] = 10
>>> a
{'id1': {'b': 10}}
>>>
```

How can I check the existence of `a['id1']` if dict or not and only if not then do `a['id1'] = dict()`
I need to print 
`{'id1': {'a': 5, 'b': 10}}`

In PHP we don't need to define an associate array, we can assign it directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test for the presence of key `k` in `a` with:

```
if 'k' in a:
```

You can see if some object `x` is a `dict` with:

```
if isinstance(x, dict):
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict
a = defaultdict(dict)
a['id1']['a'] = 5
a['id1']['b'] = 10
```